# Is machine learning a viable tool to map accent from speech onto text/syllables?

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, feature-selection, audio-recognition

I'm quite new to coding and even newer to machine learning, so please excuse if this is a stupid question to ask.
The project I am thinking about building is a program that helps correct pitch accent (the changes in high and low in between syllables) by analyzing speech from user input.
So let's say we have a random word I want to analyze, what I give to the Program is the representation of the audio (see further down) and a count for how many syllables the audio contains. As an output I want to know for each Syllable if it is either High or Low.
Let's do an example for the English word Animal . Pitch is the blue line
As an input I give the number of syllables (3) and a representation of the audio. As an output I want to see the Syllables mapped onto either High or Low, for the example "animal" [High, Low, Low/ 1,0,0] for "malaria" (4 syllables) I'd want [LLLH/0,0,0,1].
.

In order to do this I plan to train a Neural Network (Since with those the difference in speaking pace apperently doesn't need to be controlled for) and preprocess my audio with mel frequency cepstral coefficients in order to represent the features present in human speech. (I also thought about preprocessing to represent just the pitch but i am not sure if I might take away too many features then).
As mentioned earlier as an output I want the representation of where in the word the changes in hight occur.
My training data consists of 50000 recordings of various pitch-accent-patterns over words, the recordings themselves are labeled with the pattern and the word they represent.

Does this seem doable with a Neural Network or machine learning in general?
How do I get the Syllable Count to be weighted so much that the output is directly related to the high and low of each syllable?
Do you have any ideas/tips/suggestions in general?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I think you want to recogize [tone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_(linguistics)), not [accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accent_(sociolinguistics)); cf. e.g., [Lexical Tone Recognition with an Artificial Neural Network](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2562432/).

Comment: If you are looking for a learning method map utterances to their corresponding labels e.g. [melfcc features]->[LLLH], but you don't know the alignments, assuming it is monotonic, take a look at https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~graves/icml_2006.pdf

Comment: @Emre Thanks for the quick reply! The phenomenon I am talking about is called "Pitch Accent" and it's the accent over words rather than just syllables. Tones are a part of for example Chinese whereas pitch accent is important for Japanese

Comment: @FadiBakoura This looks promising as I don't know the alignments. However I wouldn't quite know how to turn the Formulas into code at the moment.

Comment: take a look at this https://github.com/baidu-research/warp-ctc which is the standard library of doing it, there are wrappers for it to pytorch see, https://github.com/SeanNaren/warp-ctc